# Command Binding of Submenu item in Context Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, commandbinding

I have a TreeView with an hierarchical Data Template (2 levels). I have a context menu created on the first level of the tree view with 3 levels. I want to bind a command of my view model to the second level of the context menu. Unfortunately I can only get it to work when using a command in my Model, which is not what I want to do... If possible, I would like to do it all in XAML.

I have tested the pure xaml solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583507/wpf-binding-a-contextmenu-to-an-mvvm-command) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841208/binding-context-menu-commands-to-viewmodel-which-is-not-in-context-visuals-tree).
In the designer, the "Tag" is underlined blue saying

```
"Cannot resolve Property Tag in data context of type System.Windows.UIElement"
```

or, if I use "Parent.PlacementTarget....", the designer tells me that

```
PlacementTarget cannot be resolved in the data context of type System.Windows.DependencyObject.
```

The code is compileable, but my command is never reached.

This is what I have:

In a ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:UpdateToolViewModel}">
    <view:UpdateToolView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ToolNameDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type src:Element}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NameProperty.Value}" FontSize="12" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ToolGroupsDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" DataType="{x:Type src:ElementGroup}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ToolNameDataTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextProperty.Value}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Tag="{Binding ElementName=UpdateToolControl}">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add Tool" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ToolGroupContextMenuToolsItemStyle}" >
                    <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add New ..." Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddToolCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource AddToolContextMenuSource}}"/>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>            
    </TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

In the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...UpdateToolView" ... Name="UpdateToolControl">
    <TreeView Name="ToolTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding AllElementsInGroups}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ToolGroupsDataTemplate}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ToolTreeViewItemStyle}"/>
</UserControl>
```

I am already on the verge of using the command in my model, calling a method in my view model. Not nice, but I just don't seem to get it to work differently.

Comment: Also what you could do is to move the definition of your `ContextMenu` to your `UserControl`. Then you Context menu will have the data context of your `UserControl` which I assume is your `ViewModel`. REMEMBER: `ContextMenu` is NOT part of the Visual Tree. HTH

Comment: With the `ResourceDictionaries`, I try to keep the xaml code clean and structured. My `UserControl` contains a lot more xaml than shown in the example above. But I will keep your comment in mind. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just going on, trying to figure out how to add a command to the CollectionContainer Items, when I found this: [CollectionContainer Binding](https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/110860-CollectionContainer-Neue-Items-finden-RelativeSource-nicht/) (sorry, its german, but the xaml code is the relevant thing here)

Now I have added the command in the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `MenuItem` and suddenly the whole thing works (although "Tag" is still underlined blue in the designer):

```
<converter:ElementToToolTipConverter x:Key="ElementToToolTipConverter"/>
<Style x:Key="ToolGroupContextMenuToolsItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Element, Converter={StaticResource ElementToToolTipConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.AddToolCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
</Style>
```

Sometimes, it already helps thinking about something else... :)